# Can someone help me understand the variance part of this theorem?

Tags: sampling

This is distribution of the sample mean when $\sigma$ is known

Theorem 6.1: Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$

Then Var($\bar{X})$ = $\cfrac {\sigma^2}{n}$

Proof in the book: By independence, Var($\bar{X})$ = Var($\sum_{i=1}^n \cfrac{X_i}{n}$) = $\cfrac{1}{n^2}$Var($\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$) = $\cfrac {1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2) = \cfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$

Now I know sample mean is just ($\sum_{i=1}^n \cfrac{X_i}{n}$)

But where does the $\cfrac {1}{n^2}$ and $n\sigma^2$come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the basic formulas:  $E(Y^k)=\int y^kdF(y)$ where $F(y)$ is the distribution function of a random variable $Y$.  The variance  of $Y$ is $E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2$.  Now let $Y=\frac{X_i}{n}$ so $Var(\frac{X_i}{n})=\frac{E(X_i)^2}{n^2}-\frac{E(X_i)^2}{n^2}=\frac{Var(X_i)}{n^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}$.
Since  the $X_i$ are independent, the variance of the sum is $n\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}$

Comment: Thank you, I just have one question, is it dF(y) or F(y) in the basic formula? Because I have a feeling it should be the latter and want to make sure

Comment: Stieltjes integral representation (using $dF(y)$) is the most general way of expressing the integrals involving an arbitrary distribution function (CDF) of a random variable.   If you have a PDF $f(y)$ the integral would be over $f(y)dy$.

Comment: I see, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Var(kY)=k^2Var(Y)$, hence when we move $\frac1n$ out from the variance term, we get $\frac1{n^2}$.

Also for independent random variable, the sum of the variance is equal to the variance of the sum. $$Var(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^nVar( X_i)=n\sigma^2$$

Comment: I'm sorry but why does $Var(kY) = k^2Var(Y)$ could you explain it to me?

Comment: $Var(kY)=E((kY-k\bar{Y})^2)=E(k^2(Y-\bar{Y})^2))=k^2E(Y-\bar{Y})^2)=k^2Var(Y)$

Comment: Thank you this makes sense